# How to create an new array from two other arrays where the element of each index of the arrays are next to each other in the new array?

Tags: javascript

i.e.

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
let array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Then I want the resultant array to be:

`let result = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4,'d', 5, 6, 7]`

with the rest of the array with the longer length being appended to the end.

How would one do this concisely (i.e. no for of loops)?

Comment: Are `for of` loops not concise?

Comment: @Krampus yes the first one does :)

Comment: Krampus, the answer is not powerful. I recommend @Grease, he is newbie, need answer with kindness.

Comment: @trincot I was thinking of having one line solutions, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Grease, please check my second solution.

Comment: One line solutions are not so meaningful in JavaScript, as you can write almost all code on one line. Also `for of` loops, ...etc. Can you be more precise?

Comment: @trincot I'm just being dumb, using for of loops are probably better to use instead of trying to cram everything into one line which makes for an unreadable nightmare

Comment: Grease, please check my 2nd answer, Why don't you try my method?

Comment: Yes, `for` loops are actually quite clean and easy to understand when you come back to your code one year later ;-)

Comment: @trincot, good comment, actually, I am not sure I can remember JS functions after 10 years. sometimes, for loop would be helpful to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what limits you have in mind for "concise", but here is one expression:

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let result = array1.slice(0, array2.length)
                   .flatMap((x, i) => [x, array2[i]])
                   .concat(array1.slice(array2.length), 
                           array2.slice(array1.length));

console.log(result);
```

`flatMap` will replace subarrays by their individual values, so that the array has no nested arrays. In this case it turns:

```
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]
```

into:

```
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']
```

Another one:

```js
let array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let result = Array.from({length: Math.max(array1.length, array2.length)}, (_, i) =>
    i >= array1.length ? array2[i] : i >= array2.length ? array1[i] : [array1[i], array2[i]]
).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let result = array1.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  if (index < array2.length) {
    acc.push(curr, array2[index]);
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

// SECOND IS MORE POWERFUL

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

let result = array1.flatMap((val, index) => (index < array2.length ? [val, array2[index]] : val));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If the second array is longer than the first this will not work.

Comment: can u explain what ```.flatMap``` does? cause I looked it up but I dont know what it means by that it 'flattens' an array.

Comment: flatMap is kind of map that is useful to work with several arrays.
I hope you to support me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Please have a look at MDN docs. It includes more examples to make you understand easily.

Comment: The second method will not work if `arrary1.length<arrary2.length`.

Comment: Oh, my, god, @Bob, please show me your answer to beat me.

Comment: @Bob, also, Grease know how to use ternary operator.
maybe, do you think he doesn't know anything?
If yes, all answers are not suitable for him cause he doesn't know basic of basic.

Comment: Both code snippets don't work when you swap `array1` and `array2`.

Comment: @HellerStern, I just told you the truth. The answer is not rigorous enough.